# Elegir entre varias opciones introducidas por teclado - Java

Tags: java, array

Tengo una duda a ver si me pueden ayudar.
Estoy introduciendo por teclado una serie de datos (Registro, idioma, precio y horas).
Este es el código:

```
import java.util.*;

public class ejemplo{

    public static final int ESPAÑOL = 0;
    public static final int ALEMAN = 1;
    public static final int INGLES = 2;
    public static final String LEN_ESP = "Español";
    public static final String LEN_ALE = "Alemán";
    public static final String LEN_INGL = "Inglés";
    public static final int MAX_REGISTROS = 10;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
            
        int[] Id = new int[MAX_REGISTROS];
        int[] lenguaConoce = new int[MAX_REGISTROS];
        int[] Precio = new int[MAX_REGISTROS];
        int[] Horas = new int[MAX_REGISTROS];

        int Registro = 0;
        boolean valorCorrecto = true;
        Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Identifíquese:");
        valorCorrecto = entrada.hasNextInt();
        if (valorCorrecto) {
            Id[Registro] = entrada.nextInt();
            if ((!valorCorrecto) || (Id[Registro] < 100) || (Id[Registro] > 1000)) {
                valorCorrecto = false;
                System.err.println("ERROR! No ha introducido bien su ID");
            }
        }

        System.out.println("\nIdioma (Del 0 al 2)");
        System.out.print("\tEspañol (0)\n"
                + "\tAlemán (1)\n"
                + "\tInglés (2) \n");
        valorCorrecto = entrada.hasNextInt();
        if (valorCorrecto) {
            lenguaConoce[Registro] = entrada.nextInt();
            if (!valorCorrecto || (lenguaConoce[Registro] < 0) || (lenguaConoce[Registro] > 3)) {
                valorCorrecto = false;
                System.err.println("ERROR!: No ha introducido bien su lengua)\n");
            } else {
                switch (lenguaConoce[Registro]) {
                    case ESPAÑOL:
                        System.out.println("Escogió el 0. Imparte " + LEN_ESP + "\n");
                        break;
                    case ALEMAN:
                        System.out.println("Escogió el 1. Imparte " + LEN_ALE + "\n");
                        break;
                    case INGLES:
                        System.out.println("Escogió el 2. Imparte " + LEN_INGL + "\n");
                        break;
                }

                if (valorCorrecto) {
                    System.out.println("Precio (de 4 a 80€)");
                    valorCorrecto = entrada.hasNextInt();
                    if (valorCorrecto) {
                        Precio[Registro] = entrada.nextInt();
                        if (!valorCorrecto || (Precio[Registro] < 4) || (Precio[Registro] > 80)) {
                            valorCorrecto = false;
                            System.err.println("ERROR! Ese precio no es válido");
                        }
                    } else {
                        entrada.next();
                    }
                    System.out.println("El precio es de " + Precio[Registro] + "€/hora\n");

                    if (valorCorrecto) {
                        System.out.println("Horas (de 1 a 40)");
                        valorCorrecto = entrada.hasNextInt();
                        if (valorCorrecto) {
                            Horas[Registro] = entrada.nextInt();
                            if (!valorCorrecto || (Horas[Registro] < 1) || (Horas[Registro] > 40)) {
                                valorCorrecto = false;
                                System.err.println("ERROR!: Horas válidas entre 1 y 40)");
                            }
                        } else {
                            entrada.next();
                        }
                        System.out.println(Horas[Registro] + " horas disponibles\n");
                        
                    }
                }
            } System.out.println("ID   lengua   precio   horas");
            System.out.println(Id[Registro] + "    " + lenguaConoce[Registro] + "    " + Precio[Registro] + "      " + Horas[Registro]);
        }  
    }
}
```

Me gustaría que estos registros, se fuese pidiendo continuadamente hasta que la persona ya no quisiese pedir más y quedasen guardados en un array. Algo como:

```
ID     lengua   precio    horas
150    Alemán      4       5 
200    Español     5       8
170    Inglés      8      12
187    Alemán      15      4
```

A parte de lo anterior (he intentado con un do-while, pero no me ha salido).

Me gustaría poder seleccionar, una vez introducidos los registros (hasta un máximo de 10), sólo 1 de las lenguas introducidas?

Es decir, que si sólo quiero imprimir los datos de aquellos usuarios que han puesto alemán como su lengua, ¿cómo lo podría hacer? Que fuese algo como:

```
¿Qué lengua quieres ver?: 
          · Español (0) / Alemán (1) / Inglés (2)

AL MARCAR 1 (ALEMÁN). ME SALGA SÓLO:

ID    lengua   precio  horas
150    Alemán    4       5
187    Alemán   15       4
```

Gracias de antemano.
Saludos

Comment: Pues... en vez de imprimir todo sin más, compruebas primero que el idioma sea el que te interesa. Creo que con la puntuación que tienes y la cantidad de preguntas que hiciste, deberías saber ya que no respondemos preguntas si no aportas el código con el problema que indicas. Por favor utiliza el enlace para [edit] la pregunta y mostrar lo que has intentado hacer, o la única respuesta que te podemos dar es "con ifs".

Comment: Ahora lo modifico, lo siento. La verdad no lo sabía, porque he encontrado algunas así, pero tampoco era necesario la valoración negativa. Gracias por el comentario y lo tendré en cuenta siempre a partir de ahora. Saludos

Comment: Como dije, cuando vas a imprimir -> `System.out.println(Id[Registro] + "    " + lenguaConoce[Registro] + "    " + Precio[Registro] + "      " + Horas[Registro]);` añades un `if (lenguaConoce[Registro] == "Alemán") { System.out.println(Id[Registro] + "    " + lenguaConoce[Registro] + "    " + Precio[Registro] + "      " + Horas[Registro]);}` y ya solo imprimirás las que coincidan con el Alemán.